# VBA Run-time error -2147319767 (80028029) in Public Function

Tags: excel, vba

This error popped up today in the following code:

```
Public lngLast_CS_Sheet As Long
Public lngCS1_Index As Long
Public lngCSLast_Index As Long
```

```
Public Function num_CSx_Sheets()        'Function to find total number of CS Sheets
    Dim w As Long, cs As Long
    For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
        cs = cs - CBool(UCase(Left(Sheets(w).Name, 2)) = "CS")
    Next w
    num_CSx_Sheets = cs
End Function
```

This function has been working fine for several years but produces the error when w = 17 & cs = 4

I have checked the range of CS sheets for user mis-naming but cannot find any issues.

The function is called by the following code:

```
Sub BoMLookUpMaterials_2019_Rev_B()
'
' BoMSearch CS Sheets Macro - Modified 11/01/19 - PRS
'
Dim FirstSheet As Integer
Dim LastSheet As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim FirstRow As Integer
Dim ItemQTY As Single
Dim sSheetName As String
Dim sItemName As String

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row                      'Find last row of BoM (Qty) Col Q
End With
'
sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name                                            'Get sheet name of active Database sheet
'
lngLast_CS_Sheet = num_CSx_Sheets()                                     'Find total number of CS sheets
lngCS1_Index = Sheets("CS1").Index                                      'CS1 Sheet Index No.
lngCSLast_Index = Sheets("CS" & lngLast_CS_Sheet).Index                 'Last CS Sheet Index No.

Select Case sSheetName                                                  'Determines which BoM sheet initiated Update BOM procedure
```

I am not a experienced VBA programmer and can't figure out why this is occurring now. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: The above Public Function was designed by user4039065 some 5 years ago and has worked perfectly in the interim period

Comment: Side note - this should really be passed a workbook reference. Could be an optional parameter that defaults to `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a code issue as further testing by making lngLast_CS_Sheet equal the number of CS sheets in the  workbook, the code runs without error. This error has only occurred in this workbook and not others with exactly the same code modules. Therefore I conclude this to be a user induced error somewhere within the workbook which I will tray & track down